# Metastability in 3 or 2 flop synchronizer if input is valid for at least 2 clocks

Tags: flipflop, timing-analysis, cdc, metastability

In this image:

[image: metastability in 2 or 3 flop synchronizer]

*Figure 1: metastability in 2 or 3 flop synchronizer*

If the metastability of first flop doesn't get resolved in 4th clock, is it possible that it may get resolved to '0' in 5th clock? Or the input will force the flop's output to go to '1' in 5th clock?
Is there any other worst case that may happen?

Comment: Your question looks confusing to me. If you are talking about flop-synchronizers, why you have mentioned FIFOs in your diagram? Also, which is the signal which is crossing domains? Update the question accordingly.

Comment: I can't really follow your question, please add a schematic with signals that are labeled the same as those in the timing diagram. In general, when a metastable state resolves you will not know whether it resolves to a 1 or a 0, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: @MituRaj main_in_full is crossing domains. It is going from clk_src to clk_dest. I agree that it should be main_out_first_flop instead.

Comment: Metastability doesn't persist more than one cycle typically. But if it's high speed design like GHz order destination clock, you would need more than 2 flops on the synchronizer to be on the  safer side. Possibility is that second flop can also go Metastable.... In your case, after metastability it doesn't necessarily settle to 'wrong' value, it can settle to any value 1/0. You can't predict it. That's why you need to ensure atleast two cycle validity at destination.  Cz at the second time sampling, it would settle to the 'right' value.

Answer (score 1):

Your latency appears to just less than 1/4 cycle and misses the “main_in_full” state by 1 clock cycle.  I suspect if you choose the inverted clock for synchronization (1/2 latency) Perhaps it may be captured in the 4th clock and unlikely the 5th and never the 6th.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a huge misunderstanding about how metastability works.

Metastability for any given FF cannot persist beyond the next clock edge. Each clock edge starts a new "window" for metastability, and only if the input was changing at the same time as the clock edge.

That's why we use two or more FFs to eliminate metastability. The second FF can only go metastable if the first FF happened to be resolving its metastability in that narrow window around the next clock edge. But that same clock edge forces the first FF into a good state in any case.